Spatie laravel query builder sort method does not work
Im making a query on laravel php for my proyect, and I have this scopes:
public function scopeLocation(Builder $query, float $latitude, float $longitude, ?float $radius = 50): Builder
    {
        $haversineFormula = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians($longitude)) + sin(radians($latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude))))";

        $query->select('products.*', \DB::raw($haversineFormula . ' AS distance'))
            ->whereRaw($haversineFormula . ' < ?', [$radius]);

        //$query->withCount('tags');

        return $query;
    }

    public function scopeDates(Builder $query, ?string $filterStartDate = null, ?string $filterEndDate = null): Builder
    {
        if (!empty($filterStartDate) && !empty($filterEndDate)) {
            $query->join('availabilities', 'products.id', '=', 'availabilities.product_id')
                ->select('products.*')
                ->whereBetween('availabilities.date', [date($filterStartDate), date($filterEndDate)])
                ->groupBy('products.id');
        }
//$query->withCount('tags');
        return $query;
    }


And this is my sort:
class TagsSort implements Sort
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
    {
        return $query->withCount('tags')
            ->orderBy('tags_count', $descending ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    }
}

With that, I get and error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags_count' in 'order clause'
If I uncomment the //$query->withCount('tags'); It works correctly. Why thats happening?

the error is simple, you don't have the tags_count on the query result . Use the ->toSql() on the end of query and see the select.

I know that that is happening but why?

It's because of the withCount is from Laravel and does that out of the box

The method withCount will place a {relation}_count attribute on the resulting models, check the docs.
In your app, if you remove withCount('tags') you don't have more the column tags_count.
